# Effective discount rate

Tags: percentages

Okay so I had a doubt. The formula for successive % change is (a+b+{ab/100}).  However, the formula for effective discount rate is (a+b-{ab/100}). (where a = first rate percent, b= second rate percent). Shouldn't the two formulaes be the same? 
Okay, so if we consider discount as a negative percentage increase, then the formula should become [-(a+b)+{ab/100}]

Any idea how it is becoming (a+b-{ab/100})?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you asking why $(1-a)(1-b)=1-a-b+ab$?

Comment: No. It is given on the internet that effective discount when 2 successive discounts are given is : a+b-(ab/100). I'm asking how did this formula come